# Crystal Reports Multiple Pages

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a very simple Crystal report document which pulls data from a db and one of these fields may in some cases be larger than the space available in the page..in these cases the print out cuts out the information that doesn't fit.

Is there a way to make the text to into a new page when it doesn't fit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure?
when a record doesn't fit in the page, it goes to next page.
Perhaps section expert -> keep together does what you want.

Comment: it seems unchecking the "keep together option" under Report->Section Expert  allowed this expand on more than one page

Answer (score 2):

Look at the properties for the field once you've placed it onto the report, and check out the Can Grow option. This should wrap the field to as many lines as are needed to fit the value in.

Answer (score 0):

Put that large field into its own sub-section?  If that's not feasible, can you expand on what you're trying to do?

Comment: the field is only bigger than one page some of the time..so if I make it larger it would print out multiple pages every time. Is there a way to make the size of the field dynamic? 

Im just creating a report from a table that hold preemptive maintenance of equipment. The description of the procedures sometimes doesn't fit in one page. Any suggestions?

Comment: I would try the combo of what the other posters said, check the 'Can Grow' option and Section Expert -> Keep Together.  Come back if that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Checking the 'New Page After' option on a section or the 'Print at Bottom of Page' option are also good ways of controlling pages in the output. Keep together is useful like others mention because you will never have a section span multiple pages if it is less than a page of output as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a field that probably is a Memo data type and you put that field in a Detail row and sometimes the length of that Memo field is so long that it exceeds the space available on the page!

Right click on that field where you have it in the Detail Section;

1. Choose "Format Field";
2. Select the "Common" tab at the top of the page;
3. Near the bottom of the "Format Editor", uncheck the box "Keep Object Together";
4. Now your Memo field will span as many pages as necessary!

Also works if you are displaying the field in column layout!